# What part of the script is printing the directory information?

Tags: sql-server, powershell-5.0

I have the following contents in PowerShell script (`Process.ps1`) that reads from SQL tables and appends results to the variables listed:

```bsh
function Query($Query) {
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
    $a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close() 
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
}

$Result = Query "SELECT * from [$cubeTable]" | Out-GridView -Wait;

$CUBE = Query "SELECT [cube_name] FROM [$cubeTable] WHERE [cube_name] = '$CUBE_input'" | Select -ExpandProperty cube_name;

$Destination_Server = Query "SELECT [destination_server] FROM [$cubeTable] WHERE [cube_name] = '$CUBE'" | Select -ExpandProperty destination_server;

$BasePath = Query "SELECT [variable_value] FROM [$pathTable] WHERE [variable_name] = 'base_path'" | Select -ExpandProperty variable_value;

$jsonPath = Join-Path -Path $BasePath -ChildPath $jsonDirectory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $jsonPath

$JSON_file = Join-Path $jsonPath $CUBE |
             %{ ($_ + ".json") }

$processPATH = Join-Path -Path $BasePath -ChildPath $process_output_Directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $processPATH

$process_output = Join-Path $processPATH $CUBE |
                  %{ ($_ + ".txt") }

$autosysPATH = Join-Path -Path $BasePath -ChildPath $AUTOSYS_output_Directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $autosysPATH

$process_AUTOSYS_output = Join-Path $autosysPATH $CUBE |
                          %{ ($_ + "_process.txt") }
```

When I run the script in CMD through a batch file, it runs great as it should, however, it's outputting these directory information somewhere from the following variables:

> json_file, process_output, and autosys_output

I have an output image here: [image: output]

Where exactly is the writing to console happening? I don't have any echo OR a `Write-Host`! let alone a function to output the directories...

and its definitely not this part: `$Result = Query "SELECT * from [$cubeTable]" | Out-GridView -Wait;` because I commented it out and it still outputted the directories info as the screenshot shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`New-Item` returns the created `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` object. That's what you're seeing in your output. PowerShell default output formating just merges similar consecutive objects to provide more compact output, so you're getting a single table instead of three separate tables with one object each.

You can suppress the output by adding `| Out-Null` to the `New-Item` statements:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $jsonPath | Out-Null
```

Other options would be capturing the output in a variable or using redirection (`> $null`).

Comment: perfect! thanks for the explanation and recommended suppressing solution :)